# $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to find functions that are their own inverse function, so that

$$f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$$

and

$$f(f(x)) = x$$

I have managed to find the following examples:

$$f(x) = x$$

$$f(x) = -x + n$$

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x - n} + n$$

Are there more examples?

Comment: There are infinitely many examples, as you can take any graph that starts on the line $x=y$ and never crosses the line, and mirror the graph to the other side

Comment: Do you want continuous functions?  What about the domain?  Technically the function $f : \{c\} \to \{c \}$ given by $f(c) = c$ is its own inverse for all $c$.

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{a-x^n}$

Comment: @5xum Why should such a thing be a *function*?